# Java - Como deixo o IP Permanente de Conexão com PostGreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql

Bom dia,

Toda vez que minha máquina se conectar com a internet o IP dela muda.
Minha dúvida é... Como faço para que eu sempre consiga acessar o PostGreSQL mesmo que o IP da minha máquina mude?

```
public class ConectarDB {

private static Connection con = null;

public static Connection getConexao() {

// Drive do PostGreSQL
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }

// Variáveis de Conexão
    String drive    = "jdbc:postgresql";                // Drive do PostGreSQL
    String ip       = "localhost";                      // IP de Conexão ao Servidor
    String port     = "5432";                           // Porta do PostGreSQL
    String db       = "database_1";                     // Nome do Banco de Dados no PostGreSQL
    String user     = "postgres";                       // Nome do Usuário no PostGreSQL
    String password = "postgres";                       // Senha do Usuário no PostGreSQL
    String conexao  = drive + "://" + ip + ":" + port + "/" + db;

// Conectar-se ao Banco de Dados
    try {
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(conexao, user, password);        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível se conectar ao Banco de Dados!", "Aviso!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    // Retorno da Informação
    return con;

}

// Main
public void main(String[] args) {
    getConexao();
}
```

Comment: Júnior, você quer que sua maquina seja um servidor de banco de dados para uma aplicação de fora acessar? Porque se for apenas local, localhost é a resposta, porque mesmo que seu ip externo mude, não vai influenciar.

Comment: Bom, por em quanto pode ser sim o servidor para outros acessarem. Mais como posso fazer isso? Já que a classe vai procurar quem é localhost... e vai vê que não tem nada naquele PC. Poderia me instruir? Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente o servidor de banco de dados fica em um servidor próprio na [web  ***cloud***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing), sendo assim os servidores de datacenters possuem ip estático e não dinâmicos como as conexões que fazemos diretamente de **casa**.

E muitos desses servidores, mesmo na web, não ficam espostos diretamente, muitas vezes por questões de segurança, ficam liberados apenas no local.

Mas então, como podemos fazer a conexão com esses banco de dados?

Generalizando muitas vezes há uma própria [aplicação web](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_web) ou [web service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) rodando junto nesse servidor, nesse mesmo [datacenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_center), assim sendo possível uma conexão local.

No caso que você perguntou aqui, caso sua aplicação desktop for acessar seu banco de dados local, localhost é o correto, mas caso for distribuir para outros usuários fora da sua rede interna, você vai precisar ter um servidor na web para ter um ip fixo/estático.

Caso quiser que sua maquina seja um servidor de banco de dados mesmo com ip dinâmico, utilize um serviço como [no-ip](https://www.noip.com) para liberar um host mascarando seu ip, e cada vez que fizer a mudança de ip, a aplicação do no-ip atualiza o host com seu novo ip.

Isso é apenas uma alternativa, não muito recomendada por motivos.

Tendo um host ou ip fixo, faça uso na configuração no lugar de localhost, assim todos que tiverem com a aplicação irão acessar o mesmo banco de dados.